# How to decompress a .tar.gz file

Tags: command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install a .tar.gz  (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

I've been trying to download some linux programs, and I get.tar.gz files in my downloads. I've been trying to extract it with terminal `tar -zxvf`, and always get

> no such file or directory

I can't seem to find my root directory of the download. When I select properties on my tar.gz file, I get

> /home/Downloads

Is there no `C:\` ? I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 7 without making a custom partition, is that why ? I would really appreciate it if you guys could help me out.

Comment: No `C:\ ` in Linux. That's a Windows thing.

Comment: try: `cd Downloads` , `tar -zxvf filename.tar.gz`

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running? Most programs in latest versions of Ubuntu you can install directly from the "Ubuntu Software Centre".

Answer (score 1):

Read the most upvoted answer here : [How to install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file?rq=1)

It is the second answer. You will understand what is a tar.gz file.

Answer (score 0):

So ...

tar -zxvf uncompresses a file. Its like winRAR, but on the command line.

I am guessing you downloaded the file already, via the browser, and now you just cant find it. It seems to be on a directory called Downloads

When you open a terminal, you are on your user's directory (/home/name_of_user), and the Downloads directory is inside (/home/name_of_user/Downloads).

to go there, type `cd Downloads`

cd stands for change directory.

then type `pwd`. That says the directory you are in (it should be /home/name_of_user/Downloads)

if you are at the right place, try your tar command.

Afterward, to see all that is there, type `ls` (for list)

It'll give you a list of files in your directory.

Now,the file is extracted, and you should be able to install it per NikTh's link

A starters guide to the command line can be found http://linuxcommand.org/learning_the_shell.php

Comment: a hint, though. If you are not yet comfortable with the linux directories and command line, installing a tar.gz might be a little daunting. I suggest you acquaint yourself with the CLI (command line interface) before trying. It should not take more than a couple of hours (just the items 1,2,3 and 5 of the link I gave you should suffice for now)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have downloaded the .tar.gz file using Firefox, it is in your download directory. The download directory is `~/Downloads`.

Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> keyboard shortcut and copy and paste these line in the terminal. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after each line

```
cd ~/Downloads

tar -zxvf filename.tar.gz
```

Don't forget to change the `filename` portion with the actual name of the file. The extracted files will be also in the Downloads directory.

The directory of the download is `/home/your-login-name/Downloads` folder. not in `/home/Downloads` folder. `your-login-name` is the name you use for Login.

If you are interested in installing something from a .tar.gz file: See this question -> [How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file?rq=1)